# Do magnets effect flash storage devices?

Tags: hard-drive, usb, usb-flash-drive, flash

I'm thinking about using magnets to organize my flash drives. I have standard flash drives you can buy at any store, and some that are M.2 drives inside an enclosure (I know you can buy this too, but I don't know if that distinct would be important).

I'm thinking about taking small magnetic strips, like what is used on a fridge magnet, and sticking them on the back of the drives. This way I can stick them anywhere that's metal (e.g. server rack, leg of my desk, fridge), but I'm not sure if this would cause an issue. I assume it would be an issue for drives that are spinning magnetic discs, but because these are flash storage, I don't know if it would still cause problems.

Thanks in advance!